# Give user-creation privileges to a user

Tags: mysql, user-accounts, permissions

In MySQL, how do you allow another user to create other users? In turn, those users should only be able to  view some tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL's privileges documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create-user), the `CREATE USER` privilege is the one you want:

```
GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'username'@'host'
```

For other privileges, read [MySQL's `GRANT` documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html).

Note, I've linked to MySQL 5.0 documentation.  `GRANT` hasn't changed much over the years, so any newer versions should also use the same syntax.

Comment: Thanks. To make it work, I had to specify GRANT CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'username'@'host'...

Comment: I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `*.*` (star dot star). Stackoverflow ate my asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is this:

```
GRANT INSERT on mysql.* to 'username';
GRANT RELOAD on *.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

Plus setting grant access on the relevant tables.

Comment: Or...I'm totally wrong. I got that from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html